# Techniques/algorithms used in WAN optimization

Tags: algorithm, networking, network-programming, compression, wan

What are the techniques/algorithms used in WAN optimization? I am looking for a reference which can give a good theory supported with code examples, I have taken a look in [Steelhead](http://www.riverbed.com/products-solutions/products/wan-optimization-steelhead/) manual from Riverbed and I found the following main techniques used in:

- SDR (Scalable Data Referencing): which breaks up TCP data into
  unique data chunks, each chunk has a reference number, where when the
  same byte sequence occurs in future transmission, the reference
  number is only sent across the LAN instead of raw data chunks.
- Connection pooling: The product creates pools of idle TCP
  connection (for HTTP as example), where when a client tries to create
  a new connection to a previously visited target, it uses one from its
  pool, which, in turns, overcomes three-way TCP handshake.
- The product reduces the number of round trips over WAN for common
  actions (opening/editing remote shared files/folders), it supports
  most of intended protocols: CIFS, MAPI, HTTP … etc.
- Data compression.

Through my search I found 3 open source projects aim to do WAN optimization, these are:

- [TrafficSqueezer](http://trafficsqueezer.org/)
- [WANProxy](http://wanproxy.org/)
- [OpenNOP](http://www.opennop.org/)

TrafficSqueezer seems to have more features but the comments in its page in [sorceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/trafficsqueezer/?source=navbar) do not give a good sense about it. I tried to find a document within these projects with good info but I couldn't.

Comment: I had to debug a distributed system where the network was doing WAN optimization and it was a pain in the neck. We were using failure of a TCP connection to detect loss of connectivity and the WAN optimizer was keeping connections open by sustaining TCP keep-alive even when there was no underlying network connectivity. Eventually we persuaded the network maintainers to turn WAN optimization off and the problem went away. We were compressing the data going over the TCP connection anyway - we know from design on that some sites didn't have high-bandwidth connections.

Answer (score 1):

the techniques that can reduce the traffic amount most - are of course compression and data deduplication (both WAN optimisers built up the same data based on a algorithm on memory or HDD - as soon as there is again the same traffic pattern - the pattern is replaced with a pointer to the data and a length - therefore you can save up to 99% when you transfer the same file twice, but even different files have a lot of common data where deduplication can optimise a lot!).
(you will find a lot of sources on the web: e.g. http://www.computerweekly.com/feature/How-data-deduplication-works)
in your example this is technique called SDR.

Riverbed has also a lot of protocol support - which makes for e.g. CIFS, SMB and MAPI more delay aware (e.g. a lot of packages are buffered and sent once - so save roundtrips)
Also F5 does e.g. FTP and HTTP optimisations to get those more performant.

when there is a lot delay on the WAN link - of course you can also save time with connection pooling - so pre-established TCP sessions (you can save the time that would be needed for a tcp 3way handshake)

so at a glance:
-data deduplication
-connection pooling
-compression
-protocol optimisation

i am sure you can find a lot in the f5 doku (F5 WOM is the product), bluecoat does offer WAN optimisation as well and of course Riverbed. also silverpeak might be worth a try. 
for the opensouce ones i only have experiences on traffic squeezer, but there hasn't been a comparable feature-set to commercial products this time.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful info. Since you have experience in traffic squeezer I would like to ask you if this product can optimize the encrypted traffic such https, ssl, ..etc? I noticed lots of comments mention bad witness during installing operation?

Comment: to be honest after i needed ages to get it running - i was not testing it in that detail.
i had the feeling that i will experience a lack of support when i implement it in production.
i don't know if ssl offloading is fully supported by traffic squeezer.

all the commercial tools are able to do it.

Comment: had a talk with a colleague - it was not supported this time when we have been testing it.
BUT you can combine it with a proxy anyway to do the cert handling.
this can may give you a good start:
http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/netsysm/article.php/10954_3860256_2/WAN-Optimization-the-Open-Source-Way.htm